Stiefel-Whitney obstruction class for metalinear structures
It is a standard result that the existence of a metalinear structure on a smooth manifold is equivalent to the existence of a square root $L$ of its canonical line bundle: $$L\otimes L\cong\Omega^n\,,$$ where $n=\dim(M)$.
However, in Bates and Weinstein's "Lectures on the Geometry of Quantization" (which refers to Guillemin and Sternberg's "Geometric Asymptotics"), a different condition is given. Namely, there, it is stated that the first Stiefel-Whitney class should square to zero.
How can one see that these are equivalent? If they are at all?
